# Php cronofy integration not working. How to resolve?

Tags: php, cronofy

I have tried cronofy integration with php github code and it's not working.

https://github.com/cronofy/cronofy-php

Comment: "Not working" is not a sufficiently technical description of the problem. We need more technical details to be able to help here.

Comment: More information on the error you're seeing is going to be needed to enable us to help. The Cronofy support team is available via email at support@cronofy.com if you want to speak to someone directly.